# Weekview or Timelineview?

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have designed scheduler with unitsview, weekview and monthview,
I have a seperate list of customersname which is displayed on a listbox.
I got struck here.
Now on the weekview, I want each of the customers information to get displayed in the that particular week.
i.e(check image attached) If i click customer1 , I want all the appointments by that customers on that week to get displayed on weekview. If i click customer2, I want appointments of that customer2 on the weekview at the week.Is this possible using weekview? If not, how to implement this? Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a filter function for a particular scheduler view and make this dependent on your list of customers. [DHTMLX Filtering Events Documentation](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/filtering.html)

This technique can be used regardless of the view you are using.